# Enviar y recoger datos enviados con AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Estoy haciendo un pequeño sistema pero no logro enviar los datos con `serialize()` a mi controlador. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

JavaScript que manda los datos via AJAX:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-
      token "]').attr('content')
    }
  });

$(document).on("submit", ".form_entrada",
  function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: '0px'
    }, 200);

    var formu = $(this);
    var quien = $(this).attr("id");

    if (quien == "formEditUser") {
      var
        varurl = "updateUser";
      var
        divresul = "notificacion_resul_fanu";
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: varurl,
      datatype: 'json',
      data: formu.serialize(),
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      }
    });
  });
```

Controlador:

```
public function updateUser(){
    $input = request()->all();
    return $input;
}
```

El fichero PHP con el formulario:

```
<form id="formEditUser" method="post" action="updateUser" class="form_entrada">

  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $usuario->id; ?>">
  <div class="box-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="correo">Email</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="correo" name="correo" placeholder="ejemplo@utp.edu.pe" value="<?= $usuario->email; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="dni">Nombre</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre..." value="<?= $usuario->name; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="nombre">Tipo de Usuario</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="T1ID" name="T1ID" placeholder="Tipo..." value="<?= $usuario->T1ID; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="apellido">Habilitado</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="status" name="status" placeholder=" 0 ó 1" value="<?= $usuario->status; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="celular">Celular</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cellphone" name="cellphone" placeholder="999-999-999" value="<?= $usuario->cellphone; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <a href="users.index" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Cancelar</a>
      <!--<a href="{{ url('persons.index') }}" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</a>-->
      <button id="btnsubmit" ; type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right">Registrar</button>
      <!--<a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right">Registrar</a>-->
    </div>
</form>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('adminlte::auth.login');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    Route::get('users','UsuarioController@getList');
    Route::get('users.index','UsuarioController@index')->name('users.index');

    Route::get('formNewUser','UsuarioController@formNewUser');
    Route::get('formEditUser/{id}','UsuarioController@formEditUser');
    Route::post('updateUser', 'UsuarioController@updateUser');

    //este ultimo es el que apunta ami controlador
});
```

El error es el siguiente:

> POST http://localhost:8000/updateUser 419 (unknown status)     ?d41d:9536

Comment: Agrega tambien la ruta que creaste en web.php, para poder ver mejor que estas haciendo

Comment: amigo ya tengo eso en mi js y tambien en mi plantilla main blade tengo lo que me colocas en tu respuesta, pero sigue igual. en fin, bueno por ahora estoy enviando campo por campo nomas recepcionando todos los id's y enviando asi. gracias de todas formas

Comment: El error 419 ocurre cuando hay un problema de autenticación (en particular un timeout o una expiración de una autenticación válida).

Comment: Gracias pero ya lo resolvi, es una tonteria en realidad, mis vista a la que llamaba no tenian la extension .blade.php solo .php, al cambiar eso funciono. muchas gracias x la procupacion de quienes tomaron su tiempo para contestar.

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de leer tu ultimo comentario, es probable que a tu llamada de ajax haga falta agregarle al header el csrf_token, lo podes hacer de la siguiente manera:

**1:** En el head de tu HTML pones el siguiente meta si es que no lo tenes agregado:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

**2:** Luego lo agregas al header de la llamada de AJAX de esta forma:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "turuta",
    data: $("#form").serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(datos) {
        console.log(datos);
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        //hacer algo
    }
});
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos!

Comment: gracias por responder amigo, pero sigo con el mismo problema, el caso es que si me permite pasar data, pero de esta manera :      $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:varurl,
            datatype:'json',
            data: {data1:"datos",data2:"datos"},
            success:function(result){
                console.log(result);
            }
        });     lo que quisiera es pasar todo el formulario con form.serialize(); y no valor por valor desde javascript y acceder a sus campos desde el controlador

Comment: gracias denuevo pero no creo que ese sea el problema ya que ejecutando este codigo:                  $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:varurl,
            datatype:'json',
            // data : formu.serialize(),
            data: {name:name,age:age},
            success:function(result){
                console.log(result);
            }
        });  me envia los datos, pero al cambiar a serialize() me arroja error, ya revise en el depurardor de chrome y si me recoje los datos del formulario, ojala puedas ayudarme.

Comment: amigo ya tengo eso en mi js y tambien en mi plantilla main blade tengo lo que me colocas en tu respuesta, pero sigue igual. en fin, bueno por ahora estoy enviando campo por campo nomas recepcionando todos los id's y enviando asi. gracias de todas formas

Comment: Realmente necesitas enviarlo con serialize ? Porque puedes enviarlo como un objeto FormData en la cual enviara todo el contenido de tu formulario